# Replace NAs using na.approx or na.spline for matrix data

Tags: r, data-processing

I am quite new to R and currently have a problem, where data looks like this:

```
    ID      h1      h2     h3      h4      h5      h6     h7     h8  
    IP6_1  0.1800   NA    -0.8600  NA      0.0400 -0.1400 1.4400 1.4900  
    IP6_2 -0.0250 -0.3050 -1.1050 -1.2150  0.0250  1.2750 1.7950 1.3850  
    IP6_3  0.2125 -0.1875   NA    -1.2225 -0.1425  0.7325 1.6275 1.3975  
    IP6_4  0.0150   NA    -1.0450 -0.3550  0.2950 -0.0150 0.3850 0.3050  
    IP6_5  0.1200 -0.0900 -0.9100 -0.6500  0.0900 -0.2700 0.9100 1.1200  
    IP6_6  0.0200 -0.0200 -0.8400 -0.6600   NA    -0.0900 0.6200 0.0800
```

the data has random NAs which I want to replace using [na.approx](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/zoo/html/na.approx.html) per **row**.
I tried using it:

```
z_data <- zoo(cluster_data_wf[,-1])        
na.approx(z_data)
```

which doesn't replace any NA at all.

Some help to replace NAs by linear interpolation via approx or cubic spline interpolation via spline would be appreciated.

Edit: Final output should still have first column ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
require(zoo)
cols = colnames(x[, -1])
x = data.frame(ID=x[, 1], t(apply(x[, -1], 1, na.approx)))
colnames(x)[-1] = cols
print(x)

         ID      h1      h2     h3      h4      h5      h6     h7     h8
1 IP6_1  0.1800 -0.3400 -0.860 -0.4100  0.0400 -0.1400 1.4400 1.4900
2 IP6_2 -0.0250 -0.3050 -1.105 -1.2150  0.0250  1.2750 1.7950 1.3850
3 IP6_3  0.2125 -0.1875 -0.705 -1.2225 -0.1425  0.7325 1.6275 1.3975
4 IP6_4  0.0150 -0.5150 -1.045 -0.3550  0.2950 -0.0150 0.3850 0.3050
5 IP6_5  0.1200 -0.0900 -0.910 -0.6500  0.0900 -0.2700 0.9100 1.1200
6 IP6_6  0.0200 -0.0200 -0.840 -0.6600 -0.3750 -0.0900 0.6200 0.0800
```

Comment: awesome!
Can you explain why does the first row needs to be removed and added back again?

Comment: I removed the first column because it's a string/factor, then applied `na.approx` for each row. You need to transpose the final result.

Answer (score 2):

The question did not provide the input in a reproducible manner so we don't really know what you are starting from; however, if what we have is as given reproducibly in the Note below then since `na.approx` operates by column we transpose it except for column 1, use `na.approx`, transpose it back and fill back everything except column 1:

```
replace(DF, -1, t(na.approx(t(DF[, -1]))))
```

giving:

```
     ID      h1      h2     h3      h4      h5      h6     h7     h8
1 IP6_1  0.1800 -0.3400 -0.860 -0.4100  0.0400 -0.1400 1.4400 1.4900
2 IP6_2 -0.0250 -0.3050 -1.105 -1.2150  0.0250  1.2750 1.7950 1.3850
3 IP6_3  0.2125 -0.1875 -0.705 -1.2225 -0.1425  0.7325 1.6275 1.3975
4 IP6_4  0.0150 -0.5150 -1.045 -0.3550  0.2950 -0.0150 0.3850 0.3050
5 IP6_5  0.1200 -0.0900 -0.910 -0.6500  0.0900 -0.2700 0.9100 1.1200
6 IP6_6  0.0200 -0.0200 -0.840 -0.6600 -0.3750 -0.0900 0.6200 0.0800
```

**Note:**

```
Lines <- " ID      h1      h2     h3      h4      h5      h6     h7     h8  
    IP6_1  0.1800   NA    -0.8600  NA      0.0400 -0.1400 1.4400 1.4900  
    IP6_2 -0.0250 -0.3050 -1.1050 -1.2150  0.0250  1.2750 1.7950 1.3850  
    IP6_3  0.2125 -0.1875   NA    -1.2225 -0.1425  0.7325 1.6275 1.3975  
    IP6_4  0.0150   NA    -1.0450 -0.3550  0.2950 -0.0150 0.3850 0.3050  
    IP6_5  0.1200 -0.0900 -0.9100 -0.6500  0.0900 -0.2700 0.9100 1.1200  
    IP6_6  0.0200 -0.0200 -0.8400 -0.6600   NA    -0.0900 0.6200 0.0800 "

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Input data is as you have in note.

Comment: But the question claimed that `na.approx(zoo(DF[, -1]))` ignores the NAs which is not the case.  In fact, it replaces all NAs with a linear interpolation except for ones at the beginning or end since you need a value at each side to interpolate them.

Comment: You are right actually, the data is not exactly same as my data. NAs are not replaced when I have it at the beginning or end. 

How can na.approx be used for cases when NA is at the beginning or end?

Comment: `na.approx` uses `approx` internally and passes arguments to it so you can use the argument `rule = 2` to extend the outermost values to NAs on the ends.  See the `rule` argument in `?approx` for details.